# R list save as quoted list

Tags: r, recommenderlab

Want to save recommenderlab predict list as list of "" seperated list. I have one question in place for the same but here want to extend it with a twist.

I already tried few approaches and found below as relavent but stuck with a simple step of putting the ouptput in "" comma seperated script.

```
library("recommenderlab")
library(stringi)
data("MovieLense")
MovieLense100 <- MovieLense[rowCounts(MovieLense) >100,]
MovieLense100
train <- MovieLense100[1:50]
rec <- Recommender(train, method = "UBCF")
rec
pre <- predict(rec, MovieLense100[101:105], n = 10)
as(pre, "list")

list1 = as(pre, "list")

cat(paste0(shQuote(list1[["291"]]),collapse=","))
```

The above gives me for given user:

```
"Titanic (1997)","Contact (1997)","Alien (1979)","Amadeus (1984)","Godfather, The (1972)","Aliens (1986)","Sting, The (1973)","American Werewolf in London, An (1981)","Schindler's List (1993)","Glory (1989)"
```

I want to put user and movies in dataframe where first column will be user and second column will be movies in above concatenated form

Comment: Why is this tagged with python?

Comment: Or mongodb for that matter.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `cat(paste0(shQuote(list1[["291"]]),collapse=","))` produces the string of movie recommendations, one could do the following to turn this into a data frame tagged with a name:

```
movies <- cat(paste0(shQuote(list1[["291"]]),collapse=","))
theData <- data.frame(name="Santhosh",movies,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Another approach would be to save each movie as a separate column in the output data frame, which would make it easier to use the data in R without having to parse the movie list multiple times. The tidyverse (i.e. `tidyr` and `dplyr`) can be used to produce this data frame.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
recommendedMovies <- c("Titanic (1997)","Contact (1997)","Alien (1979)","Amadeus (1984)","Godfather, The (1972)","Aliens (1986)","Sting, The (1973)","American Werewolf in London, An (1981)","Schindler's List (1993)","Glory (1989)")
theData <- data.frame(name="Santhosh",
                      rank=1:length(recommendedMovies),
                      movies=recommendedMovies,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
theData %>% group_by(name) %>%
spread(.,rank,movies,sep="movie")
```

...and the output:

```
> theData %>% group_by(name) %>%
+ spread(.,rank,movies,sep="movie")
# A tibble: 1 x 11
# Groups:   name [1]
  name  rankmovie1 rankmovie2 rankmovie3 rankmovie4 rankmovie5 rankmovie6 rankmovie7 rankmovie8 rankmovie9
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 Sant… Titanic (… Contact (… Alien (19… Amadeus (… Godfather… Aliens (1… Sting, Th… American … Schindler…
# ... with 1 more variable: rankmovie10 <chr>
>
```

Comment: movies <- cat(paste0(shQuote(list1[["291"]]),collapse=",")) 

This gives only for "291" user, I want for all users at once with out for loop. 

The above list has  names as userid (291, 292..)

Comment: @Santhosh - Unfortunately, you only gave me the output for one user so I was unable to provide a more general answer to your question. If you update your original post to include the output from `dput()` for 5 - 10 elements in `list1`, we can figure out how to programmatically convert the entire list into a structure that has one row per user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have solved it with work around.